# How to show that the influence function of minimum density power divergence estimator with positive tuning parameter is bounded?

Tags: distributions, estimators, scoring-rules, influence-function

In the linked paper, in the influence function section, the term ${u_{\theta}(y)}{f_{\theta}(y)}^\alpha$ is directly called bounded which i do not get the explanation of? Here $\alpha > 0$ is the tuning parameter.

[link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2337385)